# Is it possible to have a PDF file open at a predefined magnification in Adobe Reader?

Tags: pdf, acrobat, adobe-reader

We have a downloadable PDF file which looks great at 72% magnification in Adobe Reader and not so good at 101%. When downloaded and opened in the reader, its default magnification is 101%.

Is there a way to define the default magnification in the PDF file itself so that we ensure the best user experience?

Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can control the URL used to download, you can put parameters in the URL to control how the built-in reader will display the file.

For example, http://example.org/doc.pdf#zoom=50 will set the magnification to 50%.

See: https://www.evermap.com/AutoBookmark/Manual/OpenParameters.htm

The above applies to the built-in reader supplied by Adobe.  Other readers may not honor the parameters. In particular, see the answer to [this question regarding Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126089/how-to-specify-parameters-to-google-chrome-adobe-pdf-viewer).

Answer (score 4):

An example of how to define magnification when opening a file (regardless of the default one):

```
AcroRd32 /A "zoom=50=OpenActions" sh.pdf
```

Comment: Any advise on defining magnification for a downloadable file? Thank you.

Comment: @aaandre - Uhmm, I'm not sure what you mean exactly. You mean like the above action but for files which are opened immediately when downloaded or .... ?

Answer (score 2):

First, this is a programming website, so you should identify a programming context.  This question will probably be closed because it belongs on the soon to be launched [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)

To set the default magnification, you need Adobe Acrobat <s>Standard</s> or Professional not Reader to have the ability to edit pdfs.  Then when you open the document, click File | Properties.  Click the Initial View tab and enter 72% in the magnification text box and click ok.  Save your pdf and reopen it.  It should default to 72% magnification when it is opened.

Note: I am unsure if other open source pdf editors provide this type of functionality.

Update: Standard doesn't work for saving magnifications.

Comment: Tried the procedure with Acrobat Standard and unfortunately the magnification level did not get saved. When opening the file, the document automatically adjusts to the adobe reader window size. The reader seems to default to Fit to window on open even when it's unselected at save time.

Comment: That's weird you couldn't do it with Standard.  I did test it with Professional and it worked, so I guess it only works with that.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

For Adobe Standard, go to "Edit" then "Preferences."
When you click on the "Page Display" tab on the left, you'll see a panel with a field called "Zoom," where you can select a percentage from a drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

If the above suggestions are not working it may be because the bookmarks can contain zoom instructions in their properties. To look at the bookmark properties select a bookmark in the bookmark panel and right click it to open properties. Choose actions. There should be a description of actions that will be applied when clicking on the bookmark.

The best solution I have found is that you can add a subsequent property for zoom instructions that will execute following the initial one, and set the page zoom to your specifications. To do this, select all of the bookmarks, right click to open properties, then actions, then choose the add function. After choosing add, find the zoom instruction that is the best fit for what you are looking for.

If you want to edit the initial zoom instruction through the edit function in bookmark properties on all bookmarks, you cannot select all, because, although the zoom will be set correctly, every bookmark will be set to one bookmark page. If you wish to edit the properties this way you must edit each, one by one.