# How to specify parameters to google chrome adobe pdf viewer?

Tags: html, css, pdf, adobe, embed

I have an embed tag like this:

```
<embed src="../../Content/PDF/StockReport.pdf#zoom=50" width="100%" height="100%">
```

the #zoom=50 is a parameter that tells the pdf reader to zoom to 50%. 
This works in all browsers but google chrome because chrome has a built in pdf viewer.

How can I pass this same parameter to google chrome's pdf viewer  ?

Comment: chrome doesn't use adobe's code at all for pdf viewing, so there may not be any equivalent, you could try css styling the embed somehow.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After checking various chrome bug reports, I can confirm that Google Chrome ignores the default functionality of Adobe PDF viewer.  At the time of this answer there is no way to pass parameters (like zoom) to the Chrome PDF viewer.

**EDIT**

Progress has been made on this by the [Chromium team](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64309). The work was being done with reference to both the [Acrobat SDK](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) and [RFC 3778](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778). As of Dec 2017 Chromium added support for `view`, `zoom`, `page`, `toolbar` and `nameddest` and later made it into Chrome.

Comment: It does understand the `page` parameter. Any others?

Comment: It also ignores `view`. I can confirm that years after this question, it still ignores `zoom`, but recognizes `page`.

Comment: Here is the Chromium Bug Report regarding PDF Open Parameters support: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64309

Comment: It supports a limited set. Namely `page=x` `scale=x`, and `toolbar=1|0`

Comment: By any chance can we rotate PDF using any parameter in chrome ? I mean by default I want to render PDF left rotated.

Answer (score 21):

Use iframe:

1. It works in Mozilla
2. It works in Chrome
3. No Javascript needed

Example:

```
<div id="mypdf">
<iframe src="/cennik.pdf#zoom=65" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
        <p>Your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: #navpanes=1&pagemode=bookmarks&view=fitH does not seem to work in Chrome. Zoom does

Answer (score 15):

Chrome 86 (2020) status of parameters - From the chromium issue (and my notes)

- `view`: implemented (accepts `Fit`, `FitH`, `FitV` - for vertical resp horizontal fit)
- `toolbar`: implemented (hides top-bar, but not zoom-buttons bottom right)
- `zoom`: implemented
- `scrollbar`: not implemented
- `page`: implemented
- `nameddest`: implemented
- `search`: filed bug 792647 to track separately
- `navpanes`: does not apply
- `statusbar`: does not apply

If you want the search functionality to be implemented [go to this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792647), login, and click the star (top left) to vote on it

Comment: Thanks for posting this. `viewrect` also seems not to be implemented. It may be useful to collect a similar list for Firefox maybe: they seem to have implemented `zoom` but have the coordinates inverted (a bug).

Comment: The Firefox bug about the y coordinate being upside-down is https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2843

Answer (score 5):

It appears that a later release of Chrome may now be the answer.  I had success passing `zoom` and `page` parameters through an `object` tag.

Case:

- Set zoom to 200%
- Set page to 2

Example:

```
<object data="https://your.url/docs/123.pdf#zoom=200&page=2" 
        type="application/pdf" 
        width="100%" 
        height="100%"> 
</object>
```

Comment: `#view=fit` works now. I didn't find documentation but there is an [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64309) on chromium which covered it and the rest of the parameters.