# HTML : How to specify PDF open parameters for Chrome native PDF reader?

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf

I am displaying some PDF documents in my web site like this :

```
<object id="pdfviewer1" data='b.pdf#page=1&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='500px' 
        height='350px'>
    <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.</p>
</object>
```

Because of native PDF reader on Chrome, all [openParams](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) options are ignored because they are specifics for Adobe Reader.

Is it possible to specify PDF open parameters for Chrome native PDF reader?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify parameters to google chrome adobe pdf viewer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126089/how-to-specify-parameters-to-google-chrome-adobe-pdf-viewer)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126089/how-to-specify-parameters-to-google-chrome-adobe-pdf-viewer/7154043#comment20538180_7154043

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am just quoting @Robotsushi answer he has written [in his topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126089/how-to-specify-parameters-to-google-chrome-adobe-pdf-viewer) for closing the question :

> After checking various chrome bug reports, I can confirm that google chrome ignores the defualt functionality of adobe pdf viewer and at the time of this answer there is no way to passing parameters like zoom to the pdf viewer in chrome.
> I hope this saves someone else some time.

EDIT:
See [the quoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126089/how-to-specify-parameters-to-google-chrome-adobe-pdf-viewer) for updated information. As of Dec 2017 Chromium added support for `view`, `zoom`, `page`, `toolbar` and `nameddest` and later made it into Chrome.

Comment: This answer is not true anymore.It supports a limited set. Namely `page=x` `scale=x`, and  `toolbar=1|0`

Comment: @samnau do you have a source for this?

Comment: it also supports `zoom=x` where x is an integer

Comment: @FrancescoB.Thanks for your contribution. As this question becomes popular, can you provide your source? Perhaps edit the answer with an example?