# Google Embedded PDF Zoom Parameter

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf

I want to embed a PDF in chrome such that that the document fills the available horizontal space of the plugin. (i.e. Minimal gray plugin background at the sides of the document).  Is there a way to pass a parameter when I embed the PDF that can specify the zoom level I want the document to open at?

Couldn't find anything recent on this topic.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108061/html-how-to-specify-pdf-open-parameters-for-chrome-native-pdf-reader) but it's a couple years old and Google changed their PDF viewer recently.

Answer (score 3):

Now it is possible.
You can provide plugin options via url.
To set document zoom to fit window width you need:

http://example.com/sample.pdf***#view=fith***

where ***fith*** - stands for *fit horizontally*

Comment: How would this work with an embedded PDF? I tried this `<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true#view=fith" width="500px" height="600px">` but it did not zoom the PDF

Comment: @martinschwartz - I found this parameter in the plugin source code. You can try to do the same with embeded document.

Comment: That's what I commented above, I tried doing so for an embedded PDF but it didn't work...

Comment: I mean try to look at source code to find why it does not work

Comment: @PavelAgarkov Where is the source code?