# Using <object> to embed pdf, does not expand to wrapping div in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf, browser

It's not a massive deal but would like consistency across browsers and the document would be easier read if it fills the box. In Chrome, increasing the 'width' only increases the margin around the pdf and not itself as it does in Firefox. Any ideas appreciated.

```
.box {
    height: 70%;
    margin-left: 22%;
    margin-top: 6%;
    width: 57%;
}

<div class="box">
   <object data="/name.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
   <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.</p>
   </object>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: I have added some parameters on the pdf such as ..name.pdf#zoom=100%" but still does not change up in Chrome. Anyone ? ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify parameters to google chrome adobe pdf viewer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126089/how-to-specify-parameters-to-google-chrome-adobe-pdf-viewer)

Comment: Short answer, they're working on it but you can't yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use iframe instead of object if you don't need the data of pdf,

```
    <div class="tip-win is-display">
        <div class="tip-head">
            <span class="tip-title">Tips</span>
            <span class="close-btn" id="close-btn">✖</span>
        </div>

        <div class="tip-content" id="tip-content">
            <div>This is a test message</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tip-foot">
            <a class="mini-button blue tip-btn" id="ok-btn">ok</a>
            <a class="mini-button blue tip-btn" id="cancel-btn">cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tip-div">
        <iframe id="tip-iframe" class="tip-iframe is-display" height="422" width="602" ></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="pdf-iframe" id="targetElementID">
        <iframe id="ipdf" src="yyytest.pdf" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

    </div>

    css:
    .tip-win {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        background: #f6f6f6;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        height: 420px;
        width: 600px;
        top: 15%;
        left: 30%
    }

    .tip-div {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 20;
        top: 15%;
        left: 30%
    }

    .pdf-iframe {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        margin-top: 45px;
        height: 90%;
        width: 100%
    }
    .tip-iframe{
        border:none;
    }
    .is-display{
        display: none;
    }
    .tip-head{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        background: #eee;
    }
    .tip-title{
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 20px;
    }
    .close-btn{
        height: 32px;
        line-height: 32px;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
        width: 32px;
        border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
    }
    .close-btn:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .tip-content{
        height: 336px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .tip-foot{
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #eee;
    }
    .tip-btn{
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 4px 16px !important;
    }

    <script>
    $('#tip-content').html(message);   

        $('.is_display').css('display','block');   
        $('.sb-btn').attr('disabled','disabled'); 

        $('.tip-btn').click(function(){  
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id==="ok-btn"){
                closeTip();
                send2SB02();
            }else{
                closeTip();
            }
        });
        // “X”
        $('#close-btn').click(closeTip);

    function closeTip() {
        $('.is_display').css('display','none');   
        $('.sb-btn').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```