# Zoom in on an element while still being able to navigate page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create the effect of zooming in on a webpage but focusing on one particular element and allowing navigating / scrolling to be present.

I found a few plugins online but none do what I'm really looking for and I've found nothing else.  Fancybox, Zoomooz etc are great but I need to be able to scroll.

The element in question is a PDF document.  I need the user to be able to zoom in and still navigate up/down the page.

Possible?

Comment: Do you have a link to the page concerned? Why would you want to do this, cant the content of the PDF be added to the page itself?

Comment: Zooming in on a PDF is usually the job of the PDF viewer plugin in the browser and likely not something you can control in a cross-browser way from outside that plugin.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126089/how-to-specify-parameters-to-google-chrome-adobe-pdf-viewer

Comment: @TomRudge I said PDF but it's actually a PDF that's been converted into JPG's and then added to a jQuery slider. http://www.steve-t-green.com/training_chap02.php#&panel1-1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you could do... http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/ and http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/mouse-wheel/index.html

However I would consider the above as a secondary option. There are many other ways to present the presentation and embed it onto your page. A slider is limited to "slide" only. You can for example use a presentation software and embed it onto your page as a widget e.g. http://prezi.com/ as freeware.

Hope that helps.