# set pdf fit to size in Iframe in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iframe

I want to display pdf in Iframe , pdf is showing but in small size. I mean I have to click on fit to size option of adobe chrome toolbar every time.

Here is code I am using

```
<iframe src='/Abc/drawings/ab-1600.pdf' height='600px' width='100%'></iframe>
```

I even tried height 100% but no success

```
<iframe src='/Abc/drawings/ab-1600.pdf' height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>
```

EDIT : just found solution which may or may not work in coming years
[How to specify parameters to google chrome adobe pdf viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126089/how-to-specify-parameters-to-google-chrome-adobe-pdf-viewer)

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<iframe src="/Abc/drawings/ab-1600.pdf" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
```