# Controlling the zoom width when a pdf is opened in a browser

Tags: html, pdf, browser

I understand browsers open pdf files in different ways and can be controlled in different methods (chrome://plugins, option>applications for Firefox etc.). Is it possible to adjust the resolution at which they are displayed at?

Say I click on a link that opens a pdf file in a new tab. Through HTML5, CSS, Javascript or some other method, is it possible to make it so that the pdf file is displayed at 100% resolution across all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. There are at least two ways that this could be achieved.

1. The individual PDFs could have an **Open Action** that defines how
   the PDF should be displayed when opened (in Acrobat this is the
   *Initial View* in the **Document Properties** dialog). Not all PDF viewing applications will support this though (including the
   plugins/extensions for viewing PDF in a browser). This would be the most universal way though as you do not have control over where users will open the PDF.
2. Determine if the various plugins have support for specifying this is part of opening a PDF. Other questions on Stackoverflow indicate that this is not possible with Google Chrome, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7154043/924).