# Size of opened PDF file by HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

on my page http://brigadatest.8u.cz/webovky/vzhled.php (I am still developing it) I have a link which opens a PDF file saved on server. The problem is, that web browsers open it minimized (80%). Is there some way, how to "say" to the browsers they have to open it maximized (cca 200%)?? You can see how it works on that page, just click on the green button with name "ceník".

Comment: You have a hyperlink to a pdf file.  When the user clicks on the link, the pdf is sent across the Internet and opened in the user's browser.  This is so common, you don't have to even mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open a new window with the zoom set, then the solution I propose would only work for Firefox but not for Chrome nor IE.

All you have to do is to append the `#zoom=100` or `#view=fit` to the end of the url and that would do the trick.

I researched about Chrome and IE not being able to interpret the zoom and view attributes, but only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126089/how-to-specify-parameters-to-google-chrome-adobe-pdf-viewer) OP that mentions Chrome.

If you want to support the major browsers, I suggest you use an `iframe`, `object` or `embed` and manipulate their zoom or view attribute.

I created [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/0CJFTVTxUtwyfHmoWgNF?p=preview) working example that makes use of iframe and set its zoom to 20% and 100%.

Hope this helps.

Comment: #zoom works in firefox and chrome :) thx! I'll try that iframe tomorrow, because #zoom doesn't work in IE and microsoft edge. However if even iframe isn't do the trick for IE, i won't really care, It's IE... :D

Comment: @Erik what version of Chrome did you test?

Comment: Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit) I downloaded it 2 days ago