# How to embed PDF file with responsive width

Tags: html, css, object, pdf, embed

I'm embedding pdf files using something like this:

```
<div class="graph-outline">
    <object style="width:100%;" data="path/to/file.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="path/to/file.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" type="application/pdf" />
    </object>
</div>
```

It works but I want to set the pdf width to match the width of the containing div. Currently it shows up like an iframe with scrollbars, so to view the entire pdf, you have to scroll right to left. I want the pdf to fit the width of the container.

How do I fix this? I'm supporting IE8 and up.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s_d_p/KTkcj/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a PDF file open at a predefined magnification in Adobe Reader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770473/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pdf-file-open-at-a-predefined-magnification-in-adobe-re)

Comment: check this links out: [SO - Q->A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770473/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pdf-file-open-at-a-predefined-magnification-in-adobe-re) and [parameters page 6](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf)

Comment: @winner_joiner: this method does not affect the pdf viewer in browsers

Comment: @dashhund: what exactly do you mean? -> the parameter should affect the way the pdf is displayed in the viewer-object (check (Doku)[http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf]). it probably depence on the Browser and plugin version. the viewer-object itself can only be resized with html/css means. or am i not understanding, what you are hinting at?

Comment: @winner_joiner: i mean that the pdf is still displayed in the same way in the viewer object on all browsers i tested it on. It seems to only have an effect when opening in reader or acrobat. (link slightly wrong btw)

Comment: @dashhund: thanks 4 the info about the link, the link is the same as above, the acrobat docu. I just tested it again(IE 11), and it works. **btw: the question was aimed at IE8+**, not all browsers (see and of the question) this link -> [Link to doku](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf?#zoom=300) should open the docu zoomed at 300% when open with IE (or at least IE11, didnt want to start my VM for older versions)

Comment: An alternative is to convert PDF to image. I don't think you can set all browsers to display same, cause they use different rendering software (Chrome has its own PDF viewer for example, which is hard to change for 'normal' users)

Answer (score 41):

Simply do this:

```
<object data="resume.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px"> 
  <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
   No biggie... you can <a href="resume.pdf">click here to
  download the PDF file.</a></p>  
</object>
```

Comment: This works well, created http://dabblet.com/gist/1cddeeb1cbc89f0a9061 to test this out too, play around with the widths and height

Comment: I see horizontal scrollbars on mobile sizes. Doesn't seem to be entirely responsive.

Comment: No this does not work.
@Carlton the example you shown also does not work.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Bootstrap 3, you can use the embed-responsive class and set the padding bottom as the height divided by the width plus a little extra for toolbars. For example, to display an 8.5 by 11 PDF, use 130% (11/8.5) plus a little extra (20%).

```
<div class='embed-responsive' style='padding-bottom:150%'>
    <object data='URL.pdf' type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='100%'></object>
</div>
```

Here's the Bootstrap CSS:

```
.embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```html
<embed src="your.pdf" type="application/pdf#view=FitH" width="actual-width.px" height="actual-height.px"></embed>
```

Check this link for all PDF Parameters: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=7

Chrome has its own PDF reader & all parameter don't work on chrome. 
Mozilla is worst for handling PDFs.

Answer (score 3):

I did that mistake once - embedding PDF files in HTML pages. I will suggest that you use a JavaScript library for displaying the content of the PDF. Like https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Comment: It's not perfect unfortunately. But a lot of the PDFs I've tried look terrible because of a font problem. (Chrome 38/Windows 7)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper{ width:100%; float:left; height:auto; border:1px solid #5694cf;}
</style>
</head>
<div id="wrapper">
<object data="http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
<p>Your web browser doesn't have a PDF Plugin. Instead you can <a href="http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf"> Click
here to download the PDF</a></p>
</object>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: the responsive width refers to the actual pdf inside the pdf-viewer object, not the object hosting the pdf-viewer

Answer (score 0):

Seen from a non-PHP guru perspective, this should do exactly what us desired to:

```
<style>
    [name$='pdf'] { width:100%; height: auto;}
</style>
```