# Zoom to fit: PDF Embedded in HTML

Tags: html, object, pdf

I am embedding a local pdf file into a simple webpage and I am looking to set the initial zoom to fit to the object size. Here is what I tried but it is not affecting the zoom.

```
 <embed src="filename.pdf?zoom=50" width="575" height="500">
```

does anyone know how to modify the code so its initial zoom is set to fit the object size.

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468961/how-to-embed-pdf-file-with-responsive-width)?

Comment: the modifier I have in the code right now is not effecting the zoom of the pdf file, I need to figure out how to make the zoom fit to the object initally

Answer (score 266):

Bit of a late response but I noticed that this information can be hard to find and haven't found the answer on SO, so here it is.

Try a differnt parameter #view=FitH to force it to fit in the horzontal space and also you need to start the querystring off with a # rather than an & making it:

```
filename.pdf#view=FitH
```

What I've noticed it is that this will work if adobe reader is embedded in the browser but chrome will use it's own version of the reader and won't respond in the same way. In my own case, the chrome browser zoomed to fit width by default, so no problem , but Internet Explorer needed the above parameters to ensure the link always opened the pdf page with the correct view setting.

For a full list of available parameters see this [doc](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)

**EDIT:** (lazy mode on)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This was great. How do I force it to refit the page to `FitH` when I resize the browser window?

Comment: The documentation for the parameters in the URL, mentioned above, has moved to this link https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: Why are you not the voted answer :)
Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way to change the color of the background container of the <embed> element? I see gray outside the document but inside the element. I'd prefer it to be transparent or inherited from the element.

Comment: I was not able to make it work in Edge. The browser ignored the parameters. Chrome supports at least some of them (e.g. view, zoom, page).

Comment: What if I want to load pdf from object data url and not using a filename.pdf?

Comment: I came back to this answer a year or two later and it saved me again - 2 votes earned if I could!

Comment: Using Wayback machine, I found the old link with the full list: https://web.archive.org/web/20140610174148/https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 29):

For me this worked(I wanted to zoom in since the container of my pdf was small):

```
    <embed src="filename.pdf#page=1&zoom=300" width="575" height="500">
```

Comment: #zoom=50 or #page=2&zoom=300 work perfectly both in chrome and IE. IE only seems to be responding to #view=Fit. More IE params here: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

Comment: I had a multiple page PDF and #zoom=100 worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

This method uses "object", it also has "embed". Either method works:

```
<div id="pdf">
    <object id="pdf_content" width="100%" height="1500px" type="application/pdf" trusted="yes" application="yes" title="Assembly" data="Assembly.pdf?#zoom=100&scrollbar=1&toolbar=1&navpanes=1">
    <!-- <embed src="Assembly.pdf" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-pdf" trusted="yes" application="yes" title="Assembly">
    </embed> -->
    <p>System Error - This PDF cannot be displayed, please contact IT.</p>
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: from the docs object or embed doesn't support percentage.

Answer (score 3):

just in case someone need it, in firefox for me it work like this

```
<iframe src="filename.pdf#zoom=FitH" style="position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Followed **@Rich** answer, I used **view=FitH** in my code to view PDF content base64 in Angular as below.

I shared for whom concern about **view base64 content PDF file with object tag using Angular** framework.

The option for view PDF

```
this.pdfContent =
      URL.createObjectURL(this.b64toBlob(content, 'application/pdf')) +
      '#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&view=FitH';
```

Read PDF content from API as

```
let content = DataHelper.getDataFromAPI();
```

When click show content button use

```
showData() {
    let content = DataHelper.getDataFromAPI();

    this.pdfContent =
      URL.createObjectURL(this.b64toBlob(content, 'application/pdf')) +
      '#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&view=FitH';

    this.pdfview.nativeElement.setAttribute('data', this.pdfContent);
  }
```

In HTML file use object tag as

```
<object #pdfview
[data]=''
type="application/pdf"
width="100%"
height="800px"
>
</object>
```

Link Angular demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tdmieb

Answer (score 1):

Bit late response to this question, however I do have something to add that might be useful for others.

If you make use of an iFrame and set the pdf file path to the src, it will load zoomed out to 100%, which the equivalence of FitH

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478120/how-to-set-fit-width-when-embedding-pdf-in-chrome/71951975#71951975

It requires creating an iframe, so it may not be ideal, but my solution provides some reusable code that I use on my websites. HTH!

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me

```
<embed src=".file-name.pdf#zoom=FitH" width="100%" height="1930px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iframe tag do display pdf file with zoom fit

```
<iframe src="filename.pdf" width="" height="" border="0"></iframe>
```