# PDF file not displaying correctly/resizing on mobile inside iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

The pdf file dosen't resize with the browser size. On mobile on chrome it shows the pdf file as a blank page. How can I get the file to resize with the browser and how to I get the pdf file to show on mobile?

My code looks like this:

```
<iframe type="application/pdf" data="mypdf.pdf" width="100%" 
height="800px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the 'data' attribute with 'src'.

Comment: When I replace it with 'data' the pdf file completely disappears .

Comment: That's because 'data' and 'type' aren't usable attributes in an <iframe> tag. 

It should look like this: <iframe src="mypdf.pdf"></iframe>

Comment: Alright removing the 'type' seemed to fix it, but how do I style it now so it would resize depending on the resolution?

Comment: I don't know much about handling pdf files, but I think this post can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562543/zoom-to-fit-pdf-embedded-in-html