# PDF embedded in html

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display the different pdf view on button click (small,large,medium etc).
I used `object` to display the pdf file.

```
<div id="pdfview">
   <object data="filename#view=FitH" type="application/pdf" style="width:100%;" id="pdfHeight" >
      <embed src="filename#view=FitH" type="application/pdf" />
   </object>
</div>
```

I need to change the pdf view without reloading, when click on a button named as `Small PDF`, then the width of the div having id `pdfview` changed to  `width:30%`.

Comment: May I ask what is a pdf view and what type of framework are you using? Plain HTML and Javascript or some JQuery too?

Comment: @Eugenio Plain HTML and JQuery

Comment: Do you just want to change the height of the pdf object on click?

Comment: @Eugenio I need to fit the PDF in the dynamic width which is small, large or medium view.

Comment: @Eugenio I want to change the width of the pdf, Large PDF means zoomed one.. Is it possible ?

Comment: See if you like the answer, if you need anything else or you have any suggestions just ask in the comments down there!
EDIT: Nevermind, I just found out what you were trying to do and will redirect you to this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562543/zoom-to-fit-pdf-embedded-in-html