# Zooming-in iFrame PDF of FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I am opening a PDF in fancybox3 using a `base64` string. It opens the `PDF` but the actual pages appear very very tiny. If I zoom-in a few times then they appear fine. 
Is there a way to set the zoom to 100% within the `open function`?

```
   $.fancybox.open({
                content: '<iframe width="80%" height="90%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + data + '" />',             
                width: 800,
                type: "html",
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the more correct fancybox usage would be something like this:

```
$.fancybox.open({
  type : 'iframe',
  src  : "data:application/pdf;base64,' + data + '",
  iframe : {
    css : {
      width: '80%',
      height: '80%'
    }
  }
});
```

(and you could also use iframe/attr to add custom properties for iframe tag)

2nd, I am not sure it is possible to change zoom level for generated pdf document. Maybe try avoiding using base64, then you would be able to set custom parameters - [Zoom to fit: PDF Embedded in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562543/zoom-to-fit-pdf-embedded-in-html)

Comment: It still appears as if it's 1 pixel document

Comment: Works fine for me, can you show some demo? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBvKBm?editors=1010

Comment: I posted my base64 on your fiddle but I can't see the PDF. I can only see white. Same as with your base64

Comment: Well, it works on ff, but I guess you need some pdf reader on your pc to make it work on other browsers. This is why I always recommend using https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ to display pdf files.