# How to set default zoom level in php header for pdf while downloading

Tags: php, pdf

I am using following header to download pdf

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Business Report.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

Is it possible to set default zoom level for pdf when we open pdf

Comment: it cant be done by script, as far as i know, but you can if you have installed adobe acrobat plugin to your browser. e.g. http://superuser.com/q/81847

Comment: try this link. This will set default level for Acrobat Reader. http://superuser.com/questions/81847/setting-the-default-zoom-level-for-acrobat-reader-browser-plugin

Comment: Or If you can control the URL used to download, this link is better solution. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770473/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pdf-file-open-at-a-predefined-magnification-in-adobe-re#answer-774128